# How to avoid text on a button from being cut off in UWP xaml

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I have a button with MinWidth set as MinWidth="118" and that works fine. But when I change the Text size in windows using Settings -> Accessibility -> Text Size -> change it to 200%, then text takes more space and that hard coded width is not sufficient so text gets cut off. So how can I set the width so that text never cuts off? Also, I do not want to calculate the new width for 200% text size because, the text of the button can change without making any code changes since that text is service delivered. So is there any way to set the width so that text on the button never cuts off?

```
<Button
    MinWidth="118"
    MinHeight="30"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind ViewModel.PrimaryActionAutomationName, Mode=OneWay}"
    BorderThickness="1"
    Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.InvokePrimaryAction}"
    Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.PrimaryAction, Mode=OneWay}"
    CornerRadius="3"
    Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any way to set the width so that text on the button never cuts off?

No, there is no such built-in feature for the `Button` control. You still need to manage the `Button` width on your own. Handle the [DisplayInformation.DpiChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.dpichanged?view=winrt-22000) and get the current **ResolutionScale** value. Then you could change the width based on the value.

**MainPage.h**

```
struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
{
    MainPage();

private:
    Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayInformation displayInfo{ nullptr };
    event_token DpiChangedToken{};

    void OnDpiChanged(Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayInformation const&, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&);


};
```

**MainPage.cpp**

```
    MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    displayInfo = DisplayInformation::GetForCurrentView();
    DpiChangedToken = displayInfo.DpiChanged({ get_weak(), &MainPage::OnDpiChanged});
}


void MainPage::OnDpiChanged(DisplayInformation const&, IInspectable const&)
{
    DisplayInformation displayInformation = DisplayInformation::GetForCurrentView();
    ResolutionScale scale = displayInformation.ResolutionScale();
   // switch logic here
}
```

Comment: @IInspectable My bad, I've changed the code into c++-winrt.

Comment: It is saying - Error C2039 'DisplayInformation': is not a member of 'winrt::Windows::Graphics::Display' when I made .h changes.

Comment: Got it. I was missing headers for this namespace.